# Problema con consulta php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

presento un problemita, tengo un codigo que he estado actualizando a mysqli, este me devuelve una consulta, pero esta, aunque este correcta por que ya la valide directamente en la base de datos siempre se va la segunda opcion or die "Couldn't execute SQL query on AsteriDex table.", por que puede pasar esto?

```
  $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM user1 WHERE id>0 order by name" ;
     $sql_result = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $sql_select)
     or die ("Couldn't execute SQL query on AsteriDex table.") ;
```

Saludos.

Comment: Esa es una muy mala práctica para verificar los errores, debes checar primero la conexión y luego la consulta, por favor guíate de la documentación oficial https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Muestra **provisionalmente** el motivo del error: `or die ("Couldn't execute SQL query on AsteriDex table." . mysqli_error($dbconnection)) ;` Así sabrás cuál es el fallo exactamente. Como bien comenta @BetaM, una vez resuelto el error, deberías consideras escribir un código más robusto, con control de errores.

Comment: Gracias muchachos, pude ver el error gracias a sus consejos, me faltaba incluir la variable bd dentro de $bdconnection.